# Why StreamWriter writes text to file with using UTF-8 without BOM?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8, streamwriter

Find out that StreamWriter uses UTF-8 without BOM by default. I understand using UTF-8, but why without BOM? http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs

Comment: The usage of a BOM in utf8 encoded text [is controversial](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1918).  The byte order mark is necessary for encoding that's sensitive to endian-ness.  Like utf16 and utf32, but not utf8.  The Unicode standard does not demand it either.

Comment: @HansPassant, BOM is used for UTF-8 to signal at the start that the text stream is encoded in UTF-8. It is important for symbols that were encoded into 2 and more bytes. Without BOM heuristic analysis is required to determine what character encoding a file is using. Applications that does not have such analysis can treat text without BOM as ASCII.

Comment: One reason is that if the text is decoded using ASCII (by accident or mistake) and the characters fall into the ASCII range, it will "just work". This is consistent with comments that they want to be maximally tolerant for readers.

Comment: I think everybody in the [c#] tag knows why a BOM in a utf8 file is a good idea.  It is just the hundreds of thousand *nix programmers that have to be convinced, they don't visit here.

Comment: @mikez, If text will be decoded using ASCII, you can get some "strange" symbols. Cent sign and greater (>=U+00A2) are endoded into 2 and more bytes.

Comment: @muradovm That is outside the standard ASCII range (0-127), in the so called extended ASCII range. That is why I qualified my statement. I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is documented that way - [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)

> StreamWriter defaults to using an instance of UTF8Encoding unless specified otherwise. This instance of UTF8Encoding is constructed without a byte order mark (BOM), so its GetPreamble method returns an empty byte array

Comment: I guess that documentation is based on implementation in code. But my question is about decision. What are benefits do not use BOM in UTF-8?

Comment: Hans already provided you with one of many links discussing the debate regarding the value of using BOM in UTF8 streams. In fact, in spite of his implication that all C# programmers are on board with his feeling that the BOM _should_ be included, suffice to say not all actually do agree on that point. The most obvious answer to your question is that the .NET designers felt that the argument against including the BOM by default is more compelling than the argument in favor of it.